# What does the "not a simple type" warning mean in Scala?

Tags: scala, types, warnings, sbt, existential-type

My Scala 2.9.1 project now emits 176 warnings, all almost exactly like this one:

```
[warn] Not a simple type:
[warn]  Type: _29.type#source.type forSome { type _29.type <: Ontology.this.TruncationFunctor } (class class scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$ExistentialType)
[warn]  Transformed: class xsbti.api.Existential
```

(It started with fewer, but my coding style seems to provoke this warning, as I'm getting more and more.)

Can anyone explain to me what this warning means, and how I should avoid it? The compiler doesn't emit any line numbers, so I'm not even sure where exactly it's coming from.

Comment: Surely if you create these as you code, you can figure out what it is that's causing them.

Comment: Try to isolate the warning by making a small test file with snippets of your code.

Comment: @RexKerr, one would think. Unfortunately they appeared during large refactorings of my code (e.g. when switching out a whole lot of type parameters to abstract type members), during which errors were drowning out the warning. Since everything compiled (with warnings) and tested at the end, I didn't stop to investigate the warnings.

Comment: @ScottMorrison - Then you are _not_ actually getting "more and more"...you just got them all in one big clump?

Comment: @RexKerr, well, they appeared in a few clumps. At some point I had 6, then 36, then 176, and today up to 304. Advancing from 176 to 304 took me by surprise --- they disappeared for a while, then after apparently trivial changes returned, multiplied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be specific to *sbt* where an assumption about types is incorrect and a warning emitted. It seems this piece of code runs when sbt needs to extract some info from source files.

See https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/blob/0.11/compile/interface/API.scala#L105

My wild guess would be a combination of existential types and type projection is causing this. You may want to report this as an sbt issue if you can narrow it down.

Comment: Thanks, huynhjl, that sets my mind at rest. I doubt I'll invest much time, but if I stumble across a small test case I'll be sure to contribute it to sbt.

Answer (score 1):

That is an SBT issue: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/830.
The level of this message was changed from warning to log at 0.13.6.

Please also take a look at the related discussion in scala-internals group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-internals/ANcaI6dVYPw/2Gt5z_S3Gc0J